# SESSION lost after location.reload()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to make login using ajax to send username and password to my php script for checking if there is any record in database, on my ajax success i want to reload the page in order to show something if session is created. I use session start on very top of my pages. Also on local server my login works perfect, but on ipage server i have this problem with losing session...(i tested it using var_dump($_SESSION) and its always `array (size=0) empty`)
I have also tried using this on my very top of pages:

```
session_save_path("your home directory path"/cgi-bin/tmp);
session_start();
```

but this also didn't work...
Also i have tried to change `session.save_path` but still same.

I am sorry for my bad English.

EDIT:
I`ve tried using form to create login but same issue still going on. Its clear now that something with the server is wrong.(maybe with the php.ini)

Comment: This may be a bit of a stretch, but did you update the "your home directory path" with the correct value? I'm assuming you got the information from the iPage knowledge base?

Comment: Yes i get that information from ipage from `Path to your Web document root` section and i am pretty sure that this path is correct.

Comment: Paste the code you are using to set the session keys.

Comment: If a found record in my database, i set session like this `$_SESSION["loggedin"] = "YES";` and i reload my page after ajax success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my host changed servers and started using a different session save path other than /var/php_sessions which didn't exist anymore. A solution would have been to declare `ini_set(' session.save_path','SOME WRITABLE PATH');` in all my script files but that would have been a pain. I talked with the host and they explicitly set the session path to a real path that did exist. Hope this helps anyone having session path troubles.

```
Location of session folder:

/domains/account/session

location of index.php

/domains/account/public_html/index.php
```

What I placed in `index.php` at line 0:

```
<?php 
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
session_start();
```

This is the only solution that worked for me. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late with my answer but I think it will be helpful to people who run into the same problem as I did.

I'm validating Login form by using jQuery and AJAX. If there are no matching records within the database then PHP script returns error but if everything is all right then PHP script stores email,passoword and loggedIn variables as sessions and returns success to jQuery. Then I put `location.reload();`
which apparently deletes session variables (all except boolean). So I used `location.reload(true);`. This solved my problem.

You can also read something more about this on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) .